# Why is the total field defined as the sum of the incident and scattered field?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, scattering

In the scalar theory of scattering, we obtain the following equation for a single cartesian component $U$ of the electric field:
$$\nabla^{2} U(\mathbf{r}, \omega)+k^{2} n^{2}(\mathbf{r}, \omega) U(\mathbf{r}, \omega)=0$$

Then, we define this component to be composed of the incident and scattered parts as:
$$U(\mathbf{r}, \omega)=U_i(\mathbf{r},\omega)+U_s(\mathbf{r}, \omega)$$

Isn't the first equation supposed to be satisfied by the whole electric field before, during, and after scattering? Could someone clarify?

Comment: "sorry for typo" – I have edited your question to correct what I thought would make sense (added the missing right brace). Feel free to further [edit] or rollback if this was intentional. Thanks!

Comment: no, the left-hand side of the equation is just a sum of U_i and U_s. Could you fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can use the [edit] link to fix it by yourself. Also, if needed, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: U(r,omega)=U_i (r,omega) + U_s (r,omega) is what I mean.